# OpenTok JS websocket connection timeout issue

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

I'm using opentok client JS api OpenTok.js 2.14.6 753045900, to set up a video conferencing app. Intermittently, it throws errors into chrome console:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://mantis002-ams.tokbox.com/rumorwebsocketsv2?socketId=12796b11-4174-431e-980f-52c29c32aa0d&attempt=b58d3a4d-7721-4e93-b39b-76224b00864a' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.`

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://mantis002-ams.tokbox.com/rumorwebsocketsv2?socketId=12796b11-4174-431e-980f-52c29c32aa0d&attempt=0d49b33e-33b9-4eec-a6d4-80ea6d7908ec' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

`OT:RumorSocket:1 Error code unavailable.`
`OT.Raptor.Socket error: e {code: 4020, message: "Error code unavailable."}`
`OT_SOCKET_CLOSE_FALLBACK_CODE: Error code unavailable.`
`OT.exception :: title: undefined (4020) msg: Error code unavailable.`

`s {code: 4020, message: "Error code unavailable.", name: "OT_SOCKET_CLOSE_FALLBACK_CODE", stack: "Error: Error code unavailable.↵    at https://stat…tatic.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js:29:247034)"}`

`An error occurred in an event handler TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of 
    null
    at index.js:455
    at P (RaptorSocket.js:75)
    at r (RaptorSocket.js:265)
    at d.triggerCallback (Dispatcher.js:32)
    at n.<anonymous> (SessionDispatcher.js:179)
    at n.emit (events.js:84)
    at d.trigger (eventing.js:321)
    at d.emit (eventing.js:330)
    at RaptorSocket.js:279`

How to correctly handle this situation, because seems like reconnection doesn't work inside OpenTok.js?
And when I tried to recreate session I received

`OT.exception :: title: Unexpected Server Response (2001) msg: Unexpected server response. Try this operation again later.`

`{ code: 2001, message: "Unexpected server response. Try this operation again later.", name: "OT_UNEXPECTED_SERVER_RESPONSE", stack: "Error: Unexpected server response. Try this operat…/static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js:23:8742)"}
mixin.js:23 OT:RumorSocket:49 The connection is being terminated because the endpoint has indicated that reconnections are not available. (CLOSE_UNSUPPORTED)`

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

Could you please email support@tokbox.com with the sessionId along with the logs? The support team will be able to help you discover the underlying issue. You can also use the [Session Inspector](https://tokbox.com/developer/tools/inspector_doc/) tool for a high-level summary that may help you pinpoint the connection errors.

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Any solution?